# Draw a line to connect points between subfigures

Tags: python, matplotlib

With matplotlib's new [subfigure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html) - not subplot - but subfigure feature. I would like to draw a line between two subfigures. From my experimentation, I don't believe connection patch (which works for subplots) works with this. Does anyone know if it possible?

Comment: What did you try for ConnectionPatch?

Comment: I just tried ConnectionPatch locally with subfigures and it seemed to work, except it did alter some aspect ratios unexpectedly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6jhl.png

Comment: Hmm, can you share your code. When I try connection patch, I get a line that is not near the coordinates at all:https://imgur.com/2RLVaBH

Comment: I posted a demo. The aspect ratio issue also went away when I stopped using constrained layout.

Comment: I see thanks, it answers this question. However, I think my main issue is that I am trying to patch between a regular plot and a surface so I cannot get the coordinates right.

Comment: Your surface plot is using `projection='3d'`?

Comment: yes exactly, I think I need to change the transforms. Trying to make an arrow. Tricky to go from nonsurface to surface though.

Comment: Tried doing some weird coordinate mapping to no avail. Ended up needing to make a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656518/mapping-a-connection-patch-between-a-regular-plot-and-a-surface-plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ConnectionPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html) works fine with subfigures, but as @JodyKlymak points out, the patch should be removed from layout calculations via [`set_in_layout(False)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_in_layout.html).

Here is an example connecting (4, 8) on the first subfigure's `ax1a` with (2, 5) on the second subfigure's `ax2`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

fig = plt.figure(layout='constrained')
sf1, sf2 = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0.07)

ax1a, ax1b = sf1.subplots(2, 1)
ax1a.scatter(4, 8)
ax1b.scatter(10, 15)

ax2 = sf2.subplots()
ax2.scatter(2, 5)

conn = ConnectionPatch(
    xyA=(4, 8), coordsA='data', axesA=ax1a,
    xyB=(2, 5), coordsB='data', axesB=ax2,
    color='red',
)
ax2.add_artist(conn)
conn.set_in_layout(False) # remove from layout calculations

plt.show()
```

[image: figure result]

Comment: You can elide the constrained_layout issue by taking the connection patch out of the layout: `con.set_in_layout(False)`.  If a patch crosses two axes, it doesn't need to be included in the layout calculation.