# Mapping a Connection Patch between a regular plot and a surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make an arrow that connects these two plots and with connection patch, I am only able to do the following:
[image].

I believe it is a coordinate transformation issue but I cannot find any details mapping 2d coords and 3d coords with connection patch. If anyone has any ideas, it would be much appreciated. I attached the code and all the functions needed to run it below:

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import lines, pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import numpy as np
import math

def fastKernelCalc(f, x, dx):
    nx = len(x) 
    kappa = np.zeros((nx, nx))
    f2 = f.transpose()
    for i in range(nx):
        for j, xj in enumerate(x):
            kernel = 0
            if i-j>0 and j!=0:
                kernel -= sum(np.diagonal(f, offset=j-i)[0:j])*dx
                for k in range(0, j):
                    kernel += sum(f2[k][k:k+i-j]*kappa[i-j+k][k:k+i-j])*dx*dx
            kappa[i][j] = kernel
    return kappa

def solveBetaFunction(x, gamma, amp):
    beta = np.zeros(len(x))
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        beta[idx] = amp*math.cos(gamma*math.acos(val))
    return beta

def buildF(x, gamma1, amp1, gamma2, amp2):
    b1 = solveBetaFunction(x, gamma1, amp1)
    b2 = solveBetaFunction(x, gamma2, amp2)
    nx = len(x)
    f = np.zeros((nx, nx))
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        for idx2, val2 in enumerate(x):
            if idx > idx2:
                f[idx][idx2] = b1[idx]*b2[idx2]
    return f

def zeroToNan(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x[0])):
            if j >= i:
                x[i][j] = float('nan')
    return x



X = 1
dx = 0.01
nx = int(round(X/dx))+1
spatial = np.linspace(0, X, nx)
f = buildF(spatial, 6,4, 6, 4)
res = 1
kernel = fastKernelCalc(f, spatial, dx)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(nrows=1, ncols=2, hspace=0)
meshx, mesht = np.meshgrid(spatial, spatial)
subfig = subfigs[1]
subfig.subplots_adjust(left=0.09, bottom=-.1, right=1, top=1.2, wspace=0.5, hspace=0)

#subfig.suptitle(r"$\hat{k}(x, y)$ and kernel error $k(x, y) - \hat{k}(x, y)$")
ax = subfig.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, subplot_kw={"projection": "3d", "computed_zorder": False})
ax.plot_surface(meshx, mesht, zeroToNan(kernel), edgecolor="black",lw=0.2, rstride=2, cstride=2, 
                        alpha=1, color="white", shade=False, rasterized=True)
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis, ax.zaxis]:
    axis._axinfo['axisline']['linewidth'] = 1
    axis._axinfo['axisline']['color'] = "b"
    axis._axinfo['grid']['linewidth'] = 0
    axis._axinfo['grid']['linestyle'] = "--"
    axis._axinfo['grid']['color'] = "#d1d1d1"
    axis.set_pane_color((0, 0, 0))
    
ax.w_zaxis.line.set_lw(0.)
ax.set_zticks([])    
ax.zaxis._axinfo['axisline']['linewidth'] = 0
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.text(1, 1, -17, s="y")

tmp_planes = ax.yaxis._PLANES 
ax.yaxis._PLANES = ( tmp_planes[2], tmp_planes[3], 
                     tmp_planes[0], tmp_planes[1], 
                     tmp_planes[4], tmp_planes[5])
xticks = [0, 1]
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks[::-1])
ax.set_yticks([], [])
test = np.zeros(nx)
vals = np.ones((len(spatial), len(spatial)))[-1]*-30
print(test.shape)
print(spatial.shape)
print(vals.shape)
print(kernel.shape)
plt.plot(test[0:], spatial[0:], vals[0:], linestyle="dotted", color="black", antialiased=False, rasterized=False)
plt.plot(spatial[0:], spatial[0:], vals[0:], linestyle="dotted", color="black", antialiased=False, rasterized=False)
zticks = np.linspace(-20, 20, 6)
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 7, s=r'$k(x, y)$', fontdict={"fontsize": 16})

ax.view_init(25,120)


subfig = subfigs[0]
subfig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.15, right=0.95, top=0.8, wspace=0.5, hspace=0)

ax2 = subfig.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
b = solveBetaFunction(spatial, 6, 1)
ax2.plot(spatial, solveBetaFunction(spatial, 5, 1))
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.set_yticks([], [])
ax2.set_xticks([0, 1])
ax2.set_xlabel("x")
space = np.linspace(0, b[0], 10)
ax2.plot(np.zeros(10), space,color="black", linestyle="dotted", markersize=1)
space = np.linspace(-1, b[-1], 20)
ax2.text(0.51, 0.7, s=r'$\lambda(x)$', fontdict={"fontsize": 16})
ax2.plot(np.ones(20), space,color="black", linestyle="dotted", markersize=1)


con = ConnectionPatch(
    xyB=(.5, .5), coordsB=ax2.transData, axesB=ax2,
    xyA=(.5, .5), coordsA=ax.transData, axesA=ax,
    color='red',
)
ax2.add_artist(con)
```

Comment: I get a [long traceback](https://pastebin.com/8yCsXmBH) when I run this. Might be better to make a smaller toy example.

Comment: I want to say thank you for your help. After a few hours of trying, I ended up just using GIMP and did it in 5 minutes. Not nearly as elegant, but not worth spending more time.